# How do i send a data from one form to function of another class

Tags: c#

I know how to pass data from one form to another form, but how can i pass data from one form to class. This is my data which i want to pass from `form1` to class Question:

```
string GrpID = "somevalue";
string DurationID = "somevalue";`
```

I searched for it but i didn't got exact answer for this.

```
class Question
{
    string GroupID="here i want this value of GroupID,how can i get this";
    string DuraID="and here value of DurationID";

    // so that i can use them here like this
    public IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestions(string topicId, int marks)
    {
        string sql = "select QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks from Questions where TopicID IN(" +
                     topicId + ") and Marks=" + marks.ToString();
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db1.mdb"));
        var rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (rs != null)
        {
            while (rs.Read())
            {
                yield return
                    new Question
                    {
                        Id = rs[0].ToString(),
                        Text = rs[1].ToString(),
                        Option1 = rs[2].ToString(),
                        Option2 = rs[3].ToString(),
                        Option3 = rs[4].ToString(),
                        Option4 = rs[5].ToString(),
                        AnswerOption = rs[6].ToString(),
                        Marks = marks
                    };
            }
        }
    }
}
public void Foo()//In this function Can i pass that `string[] conf` here?
        {
            var totQsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[0]); // isn't this just the sum of everything else?
            var mark1qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[3]); //this variable contains number of question to be display of mark 1
            var mark2qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[4]);
            var mark3Qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[5]);
            var mark4Qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[6]);

            var mark1questionSet = GetQuestions(topicId, 1).ToList();
            var mark2questionSet = GetQuestions(topicId, 2).ToList();
           }
```

Comment: can you update the question with your class? and what you want to do with the values in that class?

Comment: @Durga Why not just use a property / properties?

Comment: _so that i can use them here like this_, hmmm, where exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method to the class:

```
class Question
{

   public void SomeFunction(string grpId, string durationId)
   {
        ...
   }

}
```

Then you can call it from your form:

```
questionInstance.SomeFunction("somevalue","somevalue");
```

Comment: what if i dont want to pass that value directly in class function for eg.what if i want to pass `string[] conf = db.GetConfiguration(Convert.ToInt16(DurationID)).Split('|');`this conf array and want to use its value like this in class `totQsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[0]);`

Comment: @Durga - Then you adjust the parameter type(s) to accept a `string[]` and process it accordingly within the method.

Comment: I have edited question ,how can i adjust parameter type so that it accepts a string[] conf,because further i want to use this function like this `var mark1questionSet = GetQuestions(topicId, 1).ToList();var mark1questionSet = GetQuestions(topicId, 2).ToList();`

Comment: @Durga So change `void` to `List<Question>` and add in `string[] conf` to parameters?